# Activating Prometheus on Eclipse Hono?

Tags: eclipse-hono

i have recently installed eclipse-hono on a minikube with `driver=none`.

I want to use Grafana to show me the telemetry data and therefore I need to use Prometheus.

As you can see in the following picture, no port is assigned to Grafana or Prometheus.

[image: 1]

This port needs to be exposed as I need to access the application from outside the server, where hono is running.

How can I activate the prometheus and grafana service?

Comment: Have you installed Hono using the Helm chart? If so, you might find the answer in the README (https://github.com/eclipse/packages/blob/master/charts/hono/README.md) that comes with the chart.

Comment: yes I also installed it with the prometheus and grafana values flag and also port forwarded grafana but i cant reach it as with "minikube service list" there is no external ip set

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: https://github.com/eclipse/packages/blob/master/charts/hono/README.md#accessing-the-example-grafana-dashboard ?

Comment: I did not think i would need a .yaml file because I used  this command: "helm install --dependency-update -n hono --set prometheus.createInstance=true --set grafana.enabled=true eclipse-hono eclipse-iot/hono
"

Comment: I was referring to running `kubectl port-forward service/eclipse-hono-grafana 3000 -n hono` and then accessing the dashboard with your browser pointing to http://localhost:3000 ...

Comment: Well it is running on a server so I tried reaching it from outside with the new assigned port as I do not run it via virtual maschine (--driver=none) but it does not work. In the manual it is stated that grafana has do be activated and is deactivated by default. It says that this command should work: `mvn clean install -Pmetrics-prometheus` but it says "could not activate as metrics-prometheus does not exist". I think this may be the problem. Do you have a solution for that?